# Joint Probability of Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose I took measurements $\{X_i\}$, which are all independent and they follow a normal distribution $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$.  I am asked for the joint probability of all of the measurements.  Based on joint probability, I expect:

$$Prob(x_i=X_i)=\prod Prob(x_i)$$
$$=\prod\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Where I use $\prod$ as a product over all $i$.  Am I correct in saying this, or am I missing something important?

Comment: Bring the coefficient in front of the product to the nth power and include the subscript on the $x$ in the exponent, and you're good.

Comment: A normal distribution is usually written $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.e. with the mean and variance rather than standard deviation

Comment: Since $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$, there are other ways of writing this expression too

Comment: 1) you need $x_i$, not $x$, in the product; 2) you need the $n$-th power of $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$; 3) The product gives the *joint density function* of the $X_i$, it is not a probability.

Comment: Then what is the probability?

Comment: Any density function evaluated at a single point is NOT the probability that the random variable is equal to the point. That is, $f_{X}(x) \neq \mathbb{P}\left(X = x\right)$!

Comment: Then how would I go to P(x)?  I am asked for the probability I get that, not that I get that or more(less)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, but small correction.
$$ P(X_i= x_i) = \prod P(x_i)= \prod \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2\sigma^2)(x_i-\mu)^2}
 = \left(\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n e^{-(1/2\sigma^2)\sum (x_i-\mu)^2} $$